fatal: unable to access schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
I get this error in android studio when I want to push my codes to the gitlab:
fatal: unable to access 'https://...../': schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

the backend ssl certificated was changed before getting expired and after that I can not push my codes. I have tried git config --global http.sslBackend schannel and also I have restared my pc but still not working. how should I fix this error?

Is this gitlab instance self hosted ?

It's a private repo in gitlab and connection through vpn

The steps that I did to fix it:
restart pc
update git version by  git update-git-for-windows
Then every thig worked.
You can also temporary disable ssl verification by :
 git config --global http.sslVerify "false"

and then reenable by
git config --global http.sslVerify "true"


You can find all these settings in file .gitconfig in your user home directory. Delete wrong line.
[http]
    sslbackend = schannel
    sslVerify = true

